# How to publish ASP.NET website to a local IIS7 the easiest way?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7

So I've a local IIS7 set up. When I publish using `File System` and choose `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` as target location, the VS2010 gives the following errors:

```
Unable to add 'About.aspx' to the
   Web site.  Unable to add file
   'About.aspx'.  Access is denied.
   Unable to add 'Default.aspx' to the
   Web site.  Unable to add file
   'Default.aspx'.  Access is denied.
   Unable to add 'Global.asax' to the
   Web site.  Unable to add file
   'Global.asax'.  Access is denied.
```

etc.

I don't understand what permission I need to change from where.

When I try the 'Web Deploy' method, with '`C:\inetpub\wwwroot`' set as Service URL and '`TestWeb`' as Site/Application, it then gives me this error: "`Invalid Web Deploy service URL`".

I simply need to get this up and running so friends can access my website from outside.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about web deployment, but for the first option you probably need to run Visual Studio as Administrator so that it has permission to access the files on the C drive.

Comment: I had the same problem;  this is the answer.  You can right click on Visual Studio and select 'Run as Administrator'

Answer (score 1):

If there are existing files in the folder, you should check if they are Read-Only. 
Previously had this issue where the files where copied from a folder in VSS. As all the files in VSS are set to Read-Only all the files stated the exact same error you have above.